# Can jupyter kernekgateway print the 'code' that I commited to jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-kernel-gateway

I via ws mode to connect jupyter kernelgateway
like this: ws:xxx:8888/api/kernels/%s/channels?sessionId=xxxx

I commit the python code:

```py
import json

params = '{"abc":"123"}';
try:
    index = params.index('"""')
    print(index)
    if (index < 1):
        print("sss")
except ValueError:
    print("Element not found in the list.")
```

I can get the execution result of the code by io_pub_msg

but I can't see the '**code**' in log of kernelgateway，just find some repeat log：

```
[I 240111 05:15:20 web:2239] 200 GET /api/kernels (172.17.0.1) 0.75ms
[I 240111 05:15:20 web:2239] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs (172.17.0.1) 1.48ms
[I 2024-01-11 05:15:20.442 KernelGatewayApp] Kernel started: cc19d72d-6773-45c6-89c9-bafecf82e3f1, name: python3
[I 240111 05:15:20 web:2239] 201 POST /api/kernels (172.17.0.1) 17.14ms
[W 2024-01-11 05:15:20.646 KernelGatewayApp] No session ID specified
[I 240111 05:15:21 web:2239] 101 GET /api/kernels/cc19d72d-6773-45c6-89c9-bafecf82e3f1/channels?sessionId=5c26742c-6888-4ef4-8411-a6df22fd3641 (172.17.0.1) 584.46ms
[I 2024-01-11 05:15:22.472 KernelGatewayApp] Starting buffering for cc19d72d-6773-45c6-89c9-bafecf82e3f1:25963e1a-5e03dda3ba454441b60a8fb8
```

so how can I find it?

I want see the 'code' commited to the kernelgatwway in log file